# TLS communication between ignite pods

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, tls1.2, ignite, kubernetes-pod

I build ignite cluster in my kubernetes VM. I want to configure my ignite pods to work with tls without certificate validation.
I created a key store manually in each pod which are binary files how can I add them to be created as part of the chart deploy?
should I create the file before and add to configmap? or run a shell command during build to create them?
can you please assist I'm new to kubernetes and SSL/TLS

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your node to use appropriate ssl/tls settings per this guide: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/security/ssl-tls

docs for using a configmap to create an ignite configuration file for a node: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/kubernetes/amazon-eks-deployment#creating-configmap-for-node-configuration-file

You could set up the ssl/tls files as configmaps, or alternatively, use a stateful set and create a persistentvolume to hold the files. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

See the [image: ![enter image description here] tab on https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/kubernetes/amazon-eks-deployment#creating-pod-configuration for instructions on how to mount persistent volumes for an Ignite Stateful set.

Comment: I managed to set tls but, how can I copy keystore using kubernetes .secret ? I don't need tls.ca in ignite, only keysote is enough since I disabled  using certificate validation

Comment: you would need to mount the secret as a file and then use the appropriate mount in your ignite config. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod